# Exception handling with tasks using libraries (dll)

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library, task

I have a task which gets data using a data access library hooked up to a WCF service. layed out like so:

Data Access dll:

```
using (Service.ServiceClient client = new Service.ServiceClient(EndpointAddress))
{
    try
    {
        //Make my service call
        client.close()
        //return list
    }
    catch (FaultException fe)
    {
       client.Abort();
       throw fe;
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ce)
    {
        client.Abort();
        throw ce;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException te)
    {
        client.Abort();
        throw te;
    }
}
```

Main Program:

```
Task<List<Stuff>> loadOp = new Task<List<Stuff>>(() => dataAccessDllMethod());
loadOp.Start();
try
{
    loadOp.ContinueWith((Sender) =>
    {
        Sender.Result
    }
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Notify User
    throw;
}
```

now my code keeps breaking in the lambda expression of the loadOp meaning the user never gets notified, but from what I've read this is the correct way of error handling in tasks. is this the correct way of doing this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code I guess you don't require try catch you can directly write the code as shown below.. :-

```
 loadOp.ContinueWith((Sender) =>
        {
            ////this will be called on successful completion
            Sender.Result
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

      loadOp.ContinueWith((Sender) =>
    {
        ////Notify user
        ////This will be called when error occures
        Sender.Result
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

> The OnlyOnFaulted member of the TaskContinuationOptions enumeration
>   indicates that the continuation should only be executed if the
>   antecedent task threw an exception.

Comment: I only want to notify the user if a fault occurs though. e.g. my service times out. Otherwise I want to continue and update my list of stuff (which the `ContinueWith` does)

Answer (score 1):

When you start a `Task`, in your case a `Task<List<Stuff>>`, you **immediately** get back the Task with a promise of it to finish sometime in the future, and your method **continues execution**, meaning it will finish the `try` block and exit. It doesn't block or wait for the `Task` to complete. There are a couple of things you may do:

1. Access `Task.Result` property which waits for the Result of the `Task` while blocking the thread.
2. Invoke `Task.Wait()`, which waits for the `Task` to complete also blocking the thread.
3. `await` on the `Task`, which doesn't block like the previous two, but **yields control back to the caller, until the `Task` finishes execution**. In order to be able to do that, the compiler generates a state machine which takes care of everything for us.
4. As Neel suggested, add a continuation which take care of the previous task faulting. Note that if you try to `throw` the exception to propogate it up the call stack it won't work unless someone accesses `Result` or `Exception` properties of the continued `Task`

What i would do instead of creating different continuations for success or failure, would simply `await`:

```
Task<List<Stuff>> loadOp = Task.Run<List<Stuff>>(() => dataAccessDllMethod());
try
{
    Task<List<Stuff>> loadOp = await Task.Run<List<Stuff>>(() => dataAccessDllMethod());

    // do stuff with the result
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Notify User
    throw;
}
```

One last thing, the recommanded approach is to always use `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.Startnew` when creating tasks so you accidentally forget to `Start` them and return a `Cold Task` which never executes (using `new Task`)

Comment: This is a brilliant and well explained answer. I sadly forgot to mention I am using .Net 4.0 so Neel's solution best suited my needs

Comment: That's not a problem. You can get `Microsoft Async` from nuget: http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async

Comment: @user1 It lets you use `async / await` in .NET 4.0